# How do I catch and parse errors properly in my React form submission handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, fetch-api

I'm using React 16.13.0.  I have the following function to deal with submit events:

```
handleFormSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const NC = this.state.newCoop;
  delete NC.address.country;

  fetch('/coops/',{
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.newCoop),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
  }).then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
      }
      console.log(response.json());
      console.log(response.body);
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
  }).catch(errors => {
      console.log(errors);
      this.setState({ errors });
  });
}
```

However, I'm having an issue getting the errors properly from the response. When an error occurs, my endpoint returns a 400 request with the error text. This is what happens in curl:

```
curl --header "Content-type: application/json" --data "$req" --request POST "http://localhost:9090/coops/"
{"phone":["The phone number entered is not valid."]}
```

But the `response.statusText` contains "400 (Bad Request)". What's the right way to catch the error text and preserve it for future parsing? If my endpoint needs to format the data differently, what should it do (using Django/Python 3.7)?

**Edit:**

This is the Input component in which I'm trying to display errors:

```
<Input inputType={'text'}
    title = {'Phone'}
    name = {'phone'}
    value = {this.state.newCoop.phone}
    placeholder = {'Enter phone number'}
    handleChange = {this.handleInput}
    errors = {this.state.errors}
/>
```

And the code of the input component, `src/Input.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import {FormControl, FormLabel} from 'react-bootstrap';

const Input = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <FormLabel>{props.title}</FormLabel>
      <FormControl
          type={props.type}
          id={props.name}
          name={props.name}
          value={props.value}
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
      />

      {props.errors && props.errors[props.name] && (
          <FormControl.Feedback>
              <div className="fieldError">
                  {props.errors[props.name]}
              </div>
          </FormControl.Feedback>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Input;
```

When I run `console.log(errors)` they appear as such:

```
{phone: Array(1), web_site: Array(1)}
```

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but what happens if on your statement you try to access to errors.response? I know that if you get something that is not a 500 you can access to the response object, which will contain a data key with the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Response.ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) property API states that:

> [`Response.ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) Read only
>
> A boolean indicating whether the response was successful (status in
>   the range 200–299) or not.

That means that even `response.ok` is false, the `response.json()` will return the data.

> [`Body.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)
>
> Takes a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) stream and reads it to completion. It returns a
>   promise that resolves with the result of parsing the body text as
>   [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

So, in your code, you should define your first fetch resolve to asynchronous and if the response it's not `ok`, then `throw` with the resolved `response.json()` using `await`:

```js
handleFormSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const NC = this.state.newCoop;
  delete NC.address.country;

  fetch('/coops/',{
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.newCoop),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
  }).then(async response => { // Define the first resolve to an asynchronous function
      if (response.ok) {
          // If it's OK, resolve JSON and return the actual data
          return await response.json();
          // or better set react state
          // const data = await response.json();
          // this.setState({ data });
      } else {
          // It's not OK, throw an error with the JSON data
          // so you'll be able to catch
          throw await response.json();
      }
  }).catch(errors => {
      // Here you should get the actual errors JSON response
      console.log(errors);
      this.setState({ errors });
  });
}
```

You can check the test example working using [`fetch-mock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock) in this [Stackblitz workspace](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fetch-mock?file=index.js).

> If my endpoint needs to format the data differently, what should it do
>   (using Django/Python 3.7)?

You'll have to let us know more about how your endpoint handles the requests by providing some code and explanation.

**UPDATE**

Regarding your component and displaying the errors, the result JSON returns an array of errors for each field. If you'll only one error, then change the endpoint to return a string instead of an array or display just the first error. If you'll have multiple errors, then you can map and render through all errors array for each field:

```jsx
const Input = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <FormLabel>{props.title}</FormLabel>
      <FormControl
          type={props.type}
          id={props.name}
          name={props.name}
          value={props.value}
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
      />

      // If you just want to display the first error
      // then render the first element of the errors array
      {props.errors && props.errors[props.name] && (
        <FormControl.Feedback>
          <div className="fieldError">
            {props.errors[props.name][0]}
          </div>
        </FormControl.Feedback>
      )}

      // Or if you may have multiple errors regarding each field
      // then map and render through all errors
      {/*
      {props.errors && props.errors[props.name] && (
        <FormControl.Feedback>
          {props.errors[props.name].map((error, index) => (
            <div key={`field-error-${props.name}-${index}`} className="fieldError">
              {error}
            </div>
          ))}
        </FormControl.Feedback>
      )}
      */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, although my errors are still not appearing in my form.  This may not have anything to do with your code, but to help I edited my question and included my component and how I'm displaying the errors.  Maybe its me.

Comment: @Dave `props.errors[props.name]` is an array. You can try to get the first error by `{props.errors[props.name][0]}` or if you want to display all the errors of the `props.name` field, then you can map through the entire array like this `{props.errors[props.name].map((error, index) => (<div key={`field-error-${props.name}-${index}`} className="fieldError">{error}</div>))}`. Do you want to add it to my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `fetch` API is a little different from others. you should pass another `.then()` to the get the data and then analyze it, and using several callbacks make codes hardly to read, I use `async/await` to handle the error:

```
async handleFormSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const NC = this.state.newCoop;
  delete NC.address.country;

  try {
    const response = await fetch('/coops/',{
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.newCoop),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const result = await response.json();
      console.log('_result_: ', result);
      return result;
    }

    throw await response.json();

  } catch (errors) {

    console.log('_error_: ', errors);
    this.setState({ errors });
  }
}
```

#### Update for your new question:

Definitely, it is another question, that why the error doesn't appear, in fact, the `phone` error is and JavaScript Array, and you should show it by its way like below code, I use restructuring assignment for props:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormControl, FormLabel } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Input = ({
  title,
  type,
  name,
  value,
  placeholder,
  handleChange,
  errors,
}) => (
  <div className="form-group">
    <FormLabel>{title}</FormLabel>
    <FormControl
      type={type}
      id={name}
      name={name}
      value={value}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    {errors && errors[name] && (
      <FormControl.Feedback>
        {errors[name].map((err, i) => (
          <div key={err+i} className="fieldError">{err}</div>
        ))}
      </FormControl.Feedback>
    )}
  </div>
);

export default Input;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, although I think you're "} catch (error) {" line should "} catch (errors) {", is that right?  Anyway, I'm still not seeing my error on the screen although I can see it being thrown, but now I'm starting to wonder if this is more a problem with <FormControl.Feedback> than anything related to the components or calls.

Comment: Dear @Dave, I know you wanna settle your issue, but If your code doesn't show the error, actually it is another question. but I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really explaining what you want to do with the response. But based on your use for `throw new Error` I assume you want the following `.catch` call to handle it. In the below solution, `errors` would be assigned the object from the JSON response.

`response.json()` returns a promise. If you want to "throw" that value as an error you have to do something like this (instead of `throw new Error(...)`):

```
return response.json().then(x => Promise.reject(x))
```

Returning a rejected promise from a `.then` callback causes the promises returned by said `.then` call to be rejected as well.

In context:

```
 fetch('/coops/',{
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.newCoop),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        return response.json().then(x => Promise.reject(x));
    }).catch(errors => {
        console.log(errors);
        this.setState({ errors });
    });
```

Note: Since you are not doing anything with the return value of a successful response, the `return response.json()` inside the `if` statement is not necessary. You could rewrite that call to:

```
.then(response => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    return response.json().then(x => Promise.reject(x));
  }
})
```

> If my endpoint needs to format the data differently, what should it do (using Django/Python 3.7)?

Since we don't know what structure your component expects there is not much we can suggest. –

Answer (score 0):

let the catch part catch failure errors and then **catch the errors you need** in the then part

```
  }).then(response => {
       //use a switch to got through the responses or an if statement 
        var response = JSON.Parse(response)
        //here am assuming after you console log response you gt the correct array placement
        if(response[0]==200){
           // this indicates success
              return  JSON.stringify({"success":"true","message":"success message";})
         }else if(response[0]==400){
           // this indicates error
              return  JSON.stringify({"success":"false","message":"Error message";})
           }
  }).catch(errors => {
      console.log(errors);
      this.setState({ errors });
  });
```

on the other end you could check the first entry in the array to determine whether the query was success or failure , then handle message appropriately

Answer (score 0):

With the `fetch` API `Response` objects represent the Response meta - connection information, headers, that kind of thing.

At this stage the body has not been read.

`response.statusText` is the from the HTTP Response Status line, eg `200 Ok` or `400 (Bad Request)` in your case.

`response.ok` is a helper for checking if `response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300`

So far nothing we have looked at here is the contents of the response.

For that you need to use `response.json()`, `response.text()`, or `response.blob()`. As long as there is a body any of these functions can be used to read it - regardless of the HTTP Status Code.

Each of these functions read the body of sent to you by the server and does some kind of additional processing on it (check MDN or your preferred source of documentation for more information).

So in your case - to read and do something with the error returned to your by the server I would look at something like

```js
fetch(...)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        if (response.status === 400) {
            return Promise.reject(response.json());
        }
        return Promise.reject(new Error(`Unexpected HTTP Status: ${response.status} - ${response.statusText}`));
    })
    .then(...)
    .catch(...);
```